# Iterate Flux and concat with Mono in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I do have a `fetchEmployment()` method which does successfully fetch the records and I am iterating over it to fetch the *Mono* object based on the worker id which successfully returns the object but I am not able to create the final *Flux* which should consist of  *WorkerDTO* (list of *WorkerDTO* for normal Spring Boot application) but it returns the empty object i.e `[]`.

```java
@Override
public Flux<WorkerDTO> method() {
    Flux<EmployeeDTO> employmentDTOFlux = fetchEmployment();
    Flux<WorkerDTO> workerDTOFlux = Flux.empty();

    employmentDTOFlux.flatMap(employmentDTO -> {
        Mono<WorkerDTO> worker = workerService.findWorkerById(employmentDTO.getWorkerId());
        return Flux.concat(workerDTOFlux, Flux.from(worker));
    });

    return workerDTOFlux;
}
```

Comment: your workerDTOFlux is `Flux.empty()` and you never reassign the value, which is you get an empty array.

Comment: and whatever you tried there with `flatMap` makes no sense.

Comment: And `employmentDTOFlux.flatMap` is never excuted, because it is never subscribed to, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70569881/flatmap-a-flux-not-executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is simpler and should work as intended:

```java
@Override
public Flux<WorkerDTO> method() {
    return fetchEmployment().flatMap(employmentDTO -> {
        workerService.findWorkerById(employmentDTO.getWorkerId());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can rewrite this as something as simple as:

```
return fetchEmployment()
       .map(EmployeeDTO::getWorkerId)
       .flatMap(workerService::findWorkerById);
```

Comment: Thanks @Thomas for a quick answer. I have changed as per your answer and I have to change the return type of method to `Flux<Mono<WorkerDTO>>` from `Flux<WorkerDTO>` and when I execute the method it do throw the `ttpMessageNotWritableException: No Encoder for [reactor.core.publisher.Mono<com.xyz.dto.WorkerDTO>] with preset Content-Type 'null'"`

Comment: If you are returning the flux directly to your endpoint, for example if mapped with `@RequestMapping`, you probably have not supplied `RequestMapping.produces` to tell Spring what content type to convert to. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55355774/what-happens-when-flux-is-returned-from-spring-web-controller for an example.

Comment: Use `flatMap` to 'flatten' the `Mono`s returned from `findWorkerById` and thus avoid the need to change return type, please see my edited answer.

Comment: Can you please help here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/70846501/17456952