# Spring reactive returns scanAvailable and prefetch instead of object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have a REST API developed with Spring Reactive as below and when it returns the response it does have scanAvailable and prefetch instead of object details. We have individually APIs for the used methods below findAllEmployment, getAllWorkerAddressDetailsByWorkerId and it do return the proper response. Not sure what is wrong when I have combined them.

**WorkerDTO.java**

```
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@ToString(includeFieldNames = true)
public class WorkerDTO {
    
    ...

    private Flux<WorkerAddressDTO> workerAddress;

}
```

**ServiceImpl.java**

```java
@Override
public Flux<WorkerDTO> method() {
  Flux<EmploymentDTO> employmentDTOFlux = findAllEmployment();
  Flux<WorkerDTO> workerDTOFlux = getWorkerDetailsWithEmploymentStatus(employmentDTOFlux);
  return workerDTOFlux.flatMap(workerDTO -> {
    workerDTO.setWorkerAddress(getAllWorkerAddressDetailsByWorkerId(workerDTO.getWorkerId()).map(workerAddressDTO -> workerAddressDTO));
     return Flux.just(workerDTO);
  });
}
```

Current Response:

```
[
    {
        "xyz": "abc",
        "workerAddress": {
            "scanAvailable": true,
            "prefetch": -1
        }
    },
    {
       "xyz": "qwe",
        "workerAddress": {
            "scanAvailable": true,
            "prefetch": -1
        }
    } 
]
```

Expected Response:

```
[
    {
        "xyz": "abc",
        "workerAddress": {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2"
        }
    },
    {
       "xyz": "qwe",
        "workerAddress": {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2"
        }
    } 
]
```

Comment: You cant return a nested flux in a dto You should return a Flux<WorkerDto>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do some changes. First, drop `Flux` inside `WorkerDTO` and replace it with `List` as follows:

```java
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@ToString(includeFieldNames = true)
public class WorkerDTO {
    
    ...

    private List<WorkerAddressDTO> workerAddress;
}
```

Then, you need to change your `ServiceImpl` code as follows:

```java
@Override
public Flux<WorkerDTO> method() {
    Flux<EmploymentDTO> employmentDTOFlux = findAllEmployment();
    Flux<WorkerDTO> workerDTOFlux = getWorkerDetailsWithEmploymentStatus(employmentDTOFlux);
    return workerDTOFlux.flatMap(workerDTO -> {
         return getAllWorkerAddressDetailsByWorkerId(workerDTO.getWorkerId()).collectList()
            .map(workerAddresses -> workerDTO.setWorkerAddress(workerAddresses));
    });
}
```